# Unity Corountine started but not ending

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have the following coroutine which displays a warning error image when you click on a button and you do not have enough money:

```
public IEnumerator ShowWarning()
    {
        if (warningActive)
            yield break;
        Debug.Log("started...");
        warningActive = true;
        NotEnoughMoneyImage.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        NotEnoughMoneyImage.SetActive(false);
        warningActive = false;
        Debug.Log("ended...");
        yield break;
    }
```

NotEnoughMoneyImage is a public Image GameObject

warningActive is a public bool

It shows the debug line "started" but never shows the debug line "ended". How is that possible? I call it from another script, but I don't think that there is the problem.

Here I've got the first script which is attached to an empty object (the main parent of the shop UI). This script is the main one. At the final of it appears the IEnumerator:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;

public class WeaponShop : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static WeaponShop shop;

    public GameObject itemHolderPrefab;

    public Transform grid;

    public List<Weapon> weaponList = new List<Weapon>();

    private List<GameObject> itemHolderList = new List<GameObject>();
    public List<GameObject> buyButtonList = new List<GameObject>();

    public GameObject NotEnoughMoneyImage;
    public bool warningActive = false;
    void Start()
    {
        NotEnoughMoneyImage.SetActive(false);
        shop = this;
        FillList();
    }

    void FillList()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < weaponList.Count; ++i)
        {
            GameObject holder = Instantiate(itemHolderPrefab, grid);
            ItemHolder holderScript = holder.GetComponent<ItemHolder>();

            holderScript.itemID = weaponList[i].weaponID;
            holderScript.itemName.text = weaponList[i].weaponName;
            if (weaponList[i].weaponPrice != (int)weaponList[i].weaponPrice)
                holderScript.itemPrice.text = weaponList[i].weaponPrice.ToString("N2") + "$";
            else
                holderScript.itemPrice.text = weaponList[i].weaponPrice.ToString() + "$";

            holderScript.itemSprite.sprite = weaponList[i].weaponSprite;

            holderScript.buyButton.GetComponent<BuyButton>().weaponID = weaponList[i].weaponID;

            itemHolderList.Add(holder);
            buyButtonList.Add(holderScript.buyButton);
        }
    }

    public void SoldOutText(int weaponID)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < weaponList.Count; ++i)
            if (weaponList[i].weaponID == weaponID)
                itemHolderList[i].GetComponent<ItemHolder>().itemPrice.text = "SOLD OUT!";
    }

    public IEnumerator ShowWarning()
    {
        if (warningActive)
            yield break;
        Debug.Log("started...");
        warningActive = true;
        NotEnoughMoneyImage.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        NotEnoughMoneyImage.SetActive(false);
        warningActive = false;
        Debug.Log("ended...");
        yield break;
    }
}
```

Now the second script is attached to the "BUY" button of a prefab "Item Holder". The script above (first one) generates a number of prefabs "item holder" and fills them with the info from the inspector (weapon name, price, stats etc). Here it comes the second script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine.PlayerLoop;

public class BuyButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int weaponID;
    public TMP_Text buttonText;

    public void BuyWeapon()
    {
        if (weaponID == 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Weapon ID is ZERO");
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < WeaponShop.shop.weaponList.Count; ++i)
        {
            if (WeaponShop.shop.weaponList[i].weaponID == weaponID && !WeaponShop.shop.weaponList[i].isBought && CurrencyManager.currencyManager.RequestMoney(WeaponShop.shop.weaponList[i].weaponPrice))
            {// USING
                WeaponShop.shop.weaponList[i].isBought = true;
                CurrencyManager.currencyManager.ReduceMoney(WeaponShop.shop.weaponList[i].weaponPrice);
                WeaponShop.shop.SoldOutText(weaponID);
                UpdateBuyButton();
                // change the weapon system and update your weapon, depending on ID / name here
            }
            else if (WeaponShop.shop.weaponList[i].weaponID == weaponID && !WeaponShop.shop.weaponList[i].isBought && !CurrencyManager.currencyManager.RequestMoney(WeaponShop.shop.weaponList[i].weaponPrice))
            {//NOT ENOUGH MONEY. I know that it enters this if statement because of the debug.log
                Debug.Log("Corountine...");
                StartCoroutine(WeaponShop.shop.ShowWarning());
            }
            else if (WeaponShop.shop.weaponList[i].weaponID == weaponID && WeaponShop.shop.weaponList[i].isBought)
            {
                UpdateBuyButton();
                // change the weapon system and update your weapon, depending on ID / name here
            }
        }
    }

    void UpdateBuyButton()
    {
        buttonText.text = "USING";
        for (int i = 0; i < WeaponShop.shop.buyButtonList.Count; ++i)
        {
            BuyButton buyButtonScript = WeaponShop.shop.buyButtonList[i].GetComponent<BuyButton>();
            for (int j = 0; j < WeaponShop.shop.weaponList.Count; ++j)
            {
                if (WeaponShop.shop.weaponList[j].weaponID == buyButtonScript.weaponID && WeaponShop.shop.weaponList[j].isBought && WeaponShop.shop.weaponList[j].weaponID != weaponID)
                {
                    buyButtonScript.buttonText.text = "USE";
                }
            }
        }
        // change the weapon system and update your weapon, depending on ID / name
    }
}
```

At line 34 is the start coroutine method.

Comment: could you show the code which calls the coroutine and where is it? in update, start...and warningActive is false or true at the beginning?

Comment: I'm so sorry for being late, the other script is linked to the button. When I press the button, a function in that script is activated. And when it enteres the if statement where it should enter when I do not have enough money, it calls the StartCoroutine function. firstly, `warningActive = false;` No script is linked to the image because like you said, the sript would be disabled if I'd disable the object

Comment: Should I post the code in the question?

Comment: wo calls BuyWeapon?

Comment: the button script  (unity predefined script which is always attached to a button).  The On Click() from that script (in the inspector).

Comment: are you sure the startcoroutines is not launched twice? put a break to check that

Comment: I have a break in the first 2 lines of the coroutine. Should I put another somewhere else?

Comment: i see that Debug.Log("Corountine...");   you see that in console one or more time?

Comment: yes, I see that just one time. Sorry for late answer

Comment: I'll try more the next day. We'll figure it out. I bet:)

Comment: @Frenchy I'm sorry for wasting your time for this nooby question :)

Comment: no problem Marc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I figured it out! When I was entering the shop UI, I was pausing the game in another script. So the time scale was 0. All I had to do was to replace in the coroutine this line:

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
```

to this one:

```
yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1f);
```

That was it! Now it works just fine! For everyone which thinks the coroutine does not work well, check your time scale. It's very important (Idk how I missed it!).